# img onload function sometimes not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When loading my page, on occasion, the function called by my `<img onload=""` events come back as not defined and the images fail to display.
Is there a different way I should be calling the function to ensure that the function is defined before the img is loaded and calls it? Is there something else I am missing here?

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img onload="fader(this)" src="images/photos/image1.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img onload="fader(this)" src="images/photos/image2.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img onload="fader(this)" src="images/photos/image3.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img onload="fader(this)" src="images/photos/image4.jpg" class="galleryimage">
</div>

<script>
  function fader(obj) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(obj).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  }
</script>
```

The error:

```
photos.html:30 Uncaught ReferenceError: fader is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onload (photos.html:30)
```

Comment: My guess would be that because your script is defined after your images, if the image loads fast enough, the function is not defined. Can you try moving your script tag in front of your markup, and see if that fixes it? If it does, then either leave it, or consider using something like a document.onLoad method

Comment: To clarify for you @ryeMoss, `onload` is always called, however it gets canceled under the proccessing because `fader` isn't defined due to the fact that you made your `fader` function /after/ you've run it on the <img> block.

Comment: I had the same problem this happens because sometimes your images are loaded faster then the script is processed. I worked around this by using the setTimeout() function and waiting 1second for the script to fully load before executing the code. This is a workaround I used and might not be the best solution, but it works.

Comment: @mrdeadsven that's incorrect usage of syncs, you should use native functions such as `onload` or in JQuery lib: `.ready` `.load`.

Comment: @Luicy as I said it's a workaround that works, I wasn't allowed for the project to use JQuery and for some reason with onload it still didn't always displayed the images for some reason and this was the only Safeway for me to be sure that the images loaded in (if you know a better way in javascript to guarantee the images to display please let me know). But if you can use JQuery then you are right and it would work that way.

Comment: Ah, I see why now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery will fix it all for you. You must loop through every class as well or simply use `img[class='galleryimage']`.

```js
$(".gallery").ready(function(){
  $(".galleryimage").each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.galleryimage {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="images/photos/image1.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img src="images/photos/image2.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img src="images/photos/image3.jpg" class="galleryimage">
  <img src="images/photos/image4.jpg" class="galleryimage">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working every time. just as a note, @Toby suggestion of simply rearranging the script before the div also seemed to work.

Comment: Ah, didn't read the first couple comments since I understod your issue and didn't see anything classes as an answer, he should've posted it as an answer but oh well. Doesn't matter by now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do all your stuff with jquery?

```
$(".galleryimage").on("load", function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: this doesn't throw the error anymore, but the images will still sometimes fail to display.

Comment: This is a terrible use as it will require 4 callbacks whereas you could use one callback with a four loop.